# Встроенный ассемблер и перемещаемый код в gcc

Tags: gcc, ассемблер, c

Почему попытка сборки кода с флагом fPIC выдает ошибку?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>

int main()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x80" : : "a"(__NR_exit), "b"(0));
}
```

Сборка:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -o exit exit.c && ./exit ; echo $?
```

Ошибка:

*exit.c: In function ‘main’:*
*exit.c:6: error: can't find a register in class ‘BREG’ while reloading ‘asm’*
*exit.c:6: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На i386 позиционно независимый код обычно использует ebx для хранения адреса таблицы глобальных смещений. Поэтому ассемблер, также использующий регистр ebх, конфликтует с ним.